# SQL selecting a record based on a column but displaying all values in said column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm having an issue where a table can be setup as below.  I want to only return the records that have BA in column C but I also want to show that those records have a line for AA.

---

name,   invoice,     code,      payment

name1,    111,        BA,        $20

name1,    112,        AA,        $50

name2,    113,        AA,        $50

---

By adding code = BA in the Where clause, I am only getting line 1.  I would like to only pull the name1 name because it has an invoice with the BA code but I would also like to pull the second line because it is the same person and I want to show all payments for any person that has a BA code.  Say invoice 111 was a partial payment with an error code BA and that person came back later to correct their mistake and make an additional payment.  I want to be able to show that correction as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    name nvarchar(10),
    invoice int, 
    code nvarchar(2), 
    payment money
)

INSERT INTO @Table 
VALUES
('name1', 111, 'BA', 20),
('name1', 112, 'AA', 50),
('name2', 113, 'AA', $50)

SELECT t2.*
FROM @Table AS t
INNER JOIN @Table AS t2 ON t.name = t2.name
WHERE t.code = 'BA'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM @Table AS t
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM @Table AS t2
    WHERE t.name = t2.name AND t2.code = 'BA'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename where name in (select name from tablename where code='BA')
```

Comment: While code only answers may solve the problem, its best if you also describe why it solves the issue.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [Table] t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [name] FROM [Table] WHERE code = 'BA'
) t2 ON t2.[name] = t1.[name]
```